# How to recommend my app as a document viewer

Tags: android

When user wants to open a pdf in a application, my app being in suggested apps and user can open pdf with my app.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this intent filter to your pdf activity

```
<activity name=".YourPdfActivity">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Only include `BROWSABLE` if you want to be able to be invoked from Web browsers, which further implies that you will be able to work with `http`/`https` `Uri` schemes.

Comment: How can I find out Where is the file I have to open?

Comment: In your onCreate() method just call getIntent().getData() to access the file uri, you want to open